# Spawning Herbs when pressing every time I press the bushes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Herb collection to spawn from some bushes in the forest in my 2D game. The script I have has functions to clone Herbs prefabs, but nothing happens when I press on the bush. What is the issue here:

[image: Spawn herbs]

**Script**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform[] spawnLocations;
    public GameObject[] whatToSpawnPrefab;
    public GameObject[] whatToSpawnClone;
    

    void spawnSomethingAwesomePlease()
    {
        whatToSpawnClone[0] = Instantiate(whatToSpawnPrefab[0], spawnLocations[0].transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(0,0,0)) as GameObject;



    }
}
```

Comment: You should be parenting the clone to the canvas.  When the game is running, press the bush, and then look in the hierarchy to find the clone.   Couple notes:  spawnLocations[0] is a transform, you can use position directly from there.  Rotation should be Quaternion.identity.  Instantiate is returning a GameObject, you do not need to cast it again (remove `as GameObject`).

Comment: the thing is when i press nothing happens so i don't know it shows no clones

Comment: Does your spawn function get called?  Try adding a Debug.  Maybe the spawner is not attached to a gameObject, or the function is not called due to an incorrect condition.

Comment: I fixed it i just have another problem since i have Input GetMouseDown i press anywhere on the screen it spawns. I want to spawn it when i press specifically on the bushes.

Comment: I would avoid using the Input class for this type of interaction.  If you can make the bush a button instead of image, you can simply add a listener to the onClick event.  You may also be able to use the rect transforms rect to check if the mouse position is contained in that rect, if changing the bush to a button is not an option.  Using the rect may pose other issues, i would prefer the button option.