# Spawning 3 Items from list of Objects each time i press the button to spawn

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this script that spawns one Object only after i press on a game object that spawns it. i want to spawn a list of items like 15 or so. and spawn random 3 out of those each time i press it spawns different three from that list. how do i Achieve that. this is the script i have:

[image: Spawning herbs]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HerbSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Here, we declare variables.
    public GameObject objToSpawn;
    public Transform groupTransform;


    //public means the var is exposed in the inspector, which is super helpful.


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    Vector2 spawnPos;

    void Start()
    {
        spawnPos = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {


        //let's also spawn on button press:
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.GetRayIntersection(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition));

            if (hit.collider && hit.collider.CompareTag("Bush"))
            {
                SpawnIt();
            }
        }

        void SpawnIt()
        {
            Vector2 spawnPos = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector2(0.5f, 0.7f));
            Instantiate(objToSpawn, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity, groupTransform);
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Where is the list of the objects that you want to spawn 3 from?

Comment: i don't have it yet thats what i'm asking how do i add the list to my script and make it spawn 3 random of that list in the picture i have the list on my heirarchy but not in the script because i don't know how to implement it

Comment: Voting to close because you already asked this[Spawning Herbs when pressing every time I press the bushes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73296741/spawning-herbs-when-pressing-every-time-i-press-the-bushes)

Comment: that is a different question my friend :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign all the objects to a list via the editor and spawn it randomly by choosing randomly from the list index

```
public class HerbSpawner : MonoBehaviour {
  public Transform groupTransform;
  public GameObject[] allObjsToSpawnFrom;

  Vector2 spawnPos;

  void Start() {
    spawnPos = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
  }

  void Update() {
    // let's also spawn on button press:
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
      RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.GetRayIntersection(
          Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition));

      if (hit.collider && hit.collider.CompareTag("Bush")) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) SpawnRandomly();
      }
    }
  }

  void SpawnRandomly() {
    int ind = Random.Range(0, allObjsToSpawnFrom.Length);
    SpawnIt(allObjsToSpawnFrom[ind]);
  }

  void SpawnIt(GameObject objToSpawn) {
    Vector2 spawnPos =
        Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector2(0.5f, 0.7f));
    Instantiate(objToSpawn, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity, groupTransform);
  }
}
```

Comment: i have this error after i applied this: Assets\Scripts\Spawners\HerbSpawner.cs(36,41): error CS1002: ; expected

Comment: it needed a semicolon, I have added it. but I haven't compiled it anyway it is only to give an idea.

Comment: yeah i added that then i had this error: (35,55): error CS1061: 'GameObject[]' does not contain a definition for 'Count' and no accessible extension method 'Count' accepting a first argument of type 'GameObject[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: use Length instead of Count